# Wix should install any one feature among two features

Tags: installation, wix, wix3

I have two features in the Wix source code, Feature_A, and Feature_B., and populate the FeatureTree in the installer.
[image]

In my Use case, the installer should allow either the Feature_A or Feature_B, not both.
if the user has selected both features, the installer should warn not to proceed further.

I am not using customized dialogues for the installer. Is this possible to do this condition check as part of the standard installer sequence? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There's no concept of mutually exclusive features in MSI.  You have to modify the UI (and have corrospending gate checks for silent installations ) to not proceed if neither or both features are selected.

Another possibility is to not show this screen and abstract the selection to a radiobutton group and based on which radiobutton is selected set the corrosponding feature for installation.